# Entries of a Haar distributed unitary matrix

Tags: matrices, probability-distributions, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, random, random-matrices

The eigenvector matrix of a Wishart matrix is Haar distributed and that implies that the eigenvectors are uniformly distributed on a sphere.
I'm interested to know what is the distribution of individual entries of this haar distributed eigenvector matrix?

Answer (score 0):

So you want the marginal distribution of one of the coordinates of a uniformly distributed point on the unit sphere in $\mathbb R^n?$  Isn't its square  Beta distributed, with parameters $(1/2, (n-1)/2)$?